# Beyond acceptable range of Nested IF & formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested-if

[image]

**Values to check with**

```
 |       | Northing | Easting |
 |-------|----------|---------|
 | Inst1 | 41345    | 33467.8 |
 | inst2 | 41600.5  | 33607.2 |
 | Inst3 | 41900.8  | 33740.2 |
 | Inst4 | 41933.4  | 33780   |
 | Inst5 | 41829.5  | 33694.6 |
 | Inst6 | 41449.9  | 33539   |
```

**Range of Coordinate**

```
 |    | Northing |          | Easting |          |
 |----|----------|----------|---------|----------|
 | T1 | 41158.68 | 41396.88 | 33357.6 | 33517.57 |
 | T2 | 41307.9  | 41456.6  | 33384.2 | 33580.5  |
 | T3 | 41372.1  | 41517.5  | 33411.3 | 33607.5  |
 | T4 | 41431.6  | 41572.7  | 33435.8 | 33632.5  |
 | T5 | 41482.9  | 41654.6  | 33472.3 | 33654.2  |
 | S1 | 41564.9  | 41701.2  | 33493.1 | 33688.7  |
 | S2 | 41611.5  | 41762.3  | 33520.2 | 33708.3  |
 | S3 | 41672.7  | 41841.6  | 33555.5 | 33734.1  |
 | S4 | 41752.2  | 41897.9  | 33580.6 | 33767.6  |
 | S5 | 41809.3  | 41941.7  | 33600.1 | 33791.7  |
 | S6 | 41854.6  | 41998.7  | 33625.4 | 33810.7  |
 | T6 | 41914.8  | 42055.4  | 33650.7 | 33836.1  |
 | T7 | 41971.5  | 42137.4  | 33687.2 | 33859.9  |
```

Nested IF is not displaying the right value and can't go beyond row 48.

How can I have range M41:Q53 included?

Current formula in place below

```
=IF(N41<=$H$41<=O41 & P41<=$I$41<=Q41,M41,IF(N42<=$H$41<=O42 & 
P42<=$I$41<=Q42,M42,IF(N43<=$H$41<=O43 & 
P43<=$I$41<=Q43,M43,IF(N44<=$H$41<=O44 & 
P44<=$I$41<=Q44,M44,IF(N45<=$H$41<=O45 & 
P45<=$I$41<=Q45,M45,IF(N46<=$H$41<=O46 & 
P46<=$I$41<=Q46,M46,IF(N47<=$H$41<=O47 & 
P47<=$I$41<=Q47,M47,IF(N48<=$H$41<=O48 & P48<=$I$41<=Q48,M48,"Not 
here"))))))))
```

Comment: Are there two questions here? 1) Why is formula giving wrong result for existing range 2) Why can't i extend the formula to include M41:Q53? Also, are you receiving any kind of error message/warning? And what version of Excel are you using? (There are different restrictions on number of Nested Ifs allowed.)

Comment: Yup, That's two question which are related.
I get error message if I expand nested if further. But for now. Within its current range. It should be displaying T2, but instead it only display "Not Here". Which is the false value.

Comment: What is the error message and what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Error Msg:" The formula use more levels of nesting than you can use in the current file format" 
Currently using Excel 2016

Comment: So you have hit the [64](https://exceljet.net/nested-ifs) levels of nested IFs which suggests that question requires you to deploy some [alternative strategies](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/alternatives_to_nested_if_functions/). Though, looking at the formula it doesn't seem that deep! I see 8 levels of IF in the posted formula (does this become more nested as you go down column J?)

Comment: Done. Markdown table included. Reading the alternative strategies link you just sent to expand my formula. Column J will only refer to the northing & easting of its respective row from Inst table.

Comment: Can you explain what the end goal is?  Whatever it is, I can guarantee there's a better way than crazy nesting like this.   Are you trying to determine if a point is within a polygon?

Comment: Main objective is simple. If Inst1 Northing & Easting is within the range of T1 Northing & Easting. It'll display T1, else check for the next match.

Comment: The coordinates would form a rectangle or a sqaure when connected.

Comment: Update: I tried using CONCATENATE from the suggestion in the link. Instead of 1 false value. It display X number of false value. Where X = No of nested if. Yet still no true value

Comment: @Tyler I've been working with with coordinates a lot lately, although not very familiar with Cartesian numbering.  But if I understand correctly, there are a number of better ways to tackle this.  **Are the results in this image "correct"?**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bp1k.png

Comment: @ashleedawg yup. That is right. How did you get that?

Comment: @Tyler -  Well, this is a quick-n-dirty method that could become unruly if you have **a lot** of coordinates to compare.  How long are your lists?  Is this a one-time thing or recurring?  I'll begin an answer explaining this so far but it may or may nor be siutable for your needs.  (By the way it's only _one_ `If`` :-)

Comment: If there can be multiple matches how were you planning on returning this to the sheet? @ashleedawg has found a way i see.

Comment: Hey @QHarr, how's you're array formulas skills?   :-)

Comment: I have 600+ other inst to compare with... @qharr it would help me shortlist rather than compare with my own eyes on every single one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing coordinates, the *choice of coordinate system* doesn't change the logic very much.  :-)

It can be tricky (but not impossible) to consistently check if a point is within a polygon, but just a *plain ol' rectangle* like this is straightforward.  If you intend to compare more than a few coordinates then `nested If's` just won't work.  (In fact they should be avoided at all times!)

For my quick-n-dirty example I took your data and put it into Columns vs Rows instead of side by side.

[image: coord compare]

**The formula is `H6` is:**

```
=IF(AND(H$3>=MIN($C6:$D6),H$3<=MAX($C6:$D6),H$4>=MIN($E6:$F6),H$4<=MAX($E6:$F6)),"Match","-")
```

**Basically it's just checking:**

1. Is `Northing To Match` **greater than or equal** to `MIN of NorthingStart & NorthingEnd?
2. Is `Northing To Match` **less than or equal to** `MAX of NorthingStart & NorthingEnd?

   - If **Yes** to both then the point `Northing to Match` **is** within the specified rectangle.

There are a number of other ways this could also be tackled.  Which one is the right one depends mainly on how much data you'll be comparing, and whether it's an ongoing need (needing to account for unforeseen circumstances or not)...

The same thing could also be accomplished with side-by-side datasets with the help of an **array formula**.

**Further Reading:**

- [Introduction to Coordinate Geometry](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordintro.html) (many handy links)
- SE: Analytic Geometry: [How to check if a point is inside a rectangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle)
- Wikipedia: [Intersection_theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory)
- [How to check if two given line segments intersect?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/)

---

And a but of a tangent (no pun intended), but since I mentioned it & just for fun, a short explanation of:

### How to check if a given point lies inside or outside a polygon?

[image: Polygon1]

```
1. Draw a horizontal line to the right of each point and extend it to infinity

2. Count the number of times the line intersects with polygon edges.

3. A point is inside the polygon if either count of intersections is odd or
   point lies on an edge of polygon.  If none of the conditions is true, then 
   point lies outside.
```

[image: Polygon2]

> **How to handle point `g` in the above figure?**
>
> Note that we should returns true if the point lies on the line or same
>   as one of the [vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(geometry)) of the given polygon. To handle this, after
>   checking if the line from `p` to extreme intersects, we check whether
>   `p` is [colinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity) with vertices of current line of polygon. If it is
>   colinear, then we check if the point `p` lies on current side of
>   polygon, if it lies, we return true, else false.  <sub>([Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/))</sub>

Comment: Well you get a plus one from me. I am still struggling with array formulas!

Comment: @QHarr ah, I'm sure we'd get it figured out just fine if we tried...  another time, lol

Comment: Lol. I'm not great with defeat,despite my frequent experience of it! I have created the array which tells me where the matches are but am still trying to figure out how to reduce that array to only the elements that are matches. I'm thinking SMALL or LARGE function but not there yet.

Comment: Other potential tags for this question: [tag:geometry-surface] [tag:cartesian-coordinates]

Comment: @QHarr - Same here, probably just because I didn't have a real need or interest for it _yet_. (and that's the point I'd move the data from Excel to Access since it's so much easier to do things like that, instead of long, ugly formulas!)   But one day I'll figure it out...  Hell, a couple weeks ago I would have had no idea what surface geometry is, lol.

Comment: Did you mean : =IF(AND(H$3>=MIN($C6:$D6),H$3<=MAX($C6:$D6),H$4>:MIN($E6:$F6),H$4<=MAX($E6:$F6)),"Match","-")

Comment: Hey @ashleedawg thanks for sharing your knowledge with me. Qharr too for the help given.

Comment: You're welcome -- except you got me brainstorming on my own project & long-story-short, 4 hours later, I'm no closer to a magic formula to **calculate distance of a point from a line**. It seemed like it should be simple but I'm having trouble getting something like [this](https://study.com/academy/lesson/how-to-find-the-distance-between-a-point-a-line.html) into something usable; also to calculate "closest match to a path" like these "[which 2 of 3 are closest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2dfA.png)?" so trying to figure out [Fréchet Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frechet_distance) too

Comment: ...looks like I'll be posting a question of my own this evening,.,,.  :-)

Comment: @CharlesWilliams -- indeed I meant to use`>=` instead of `>`, thanks -- which would've given an incorrect response if the point feel exactly on the rectangle. [corrected]